# Masquerading not working, debian8

Tags: debian, networking, iptables

I have created a network namespace in debian 8 and created `veth` interface `vpngw`. On this `vpngw`, I am running OpenVPN as client and have default `gw` in this namespace towards global namespace (out from the namespace) and there I have a modem with public IP address, through which I am routing this to the OpenVPN server on the other end by using masquerading.

```
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s 10.51.31.2 -0 sierra -j MASQUERADE
```

Now the problem is, sometime it works and traffic from 10.51.31.2 (IP of `vpngw`) gets NATted and works as expected. The tunnel gets established.
But most of the times it is not hitting the iptables rule and not getting NATted.

Can anyone please help me? What is wrong here?

Comment: Is that really `-0` (zero)? What other iptables rules do you have? Is there any pattern to when it connects?

Comment: no it is " -o ". in nat table this is the one i have.

Comment: Actually let me rephrase my problem in simple word:
1) ii have a linux box , debian8
2) i have a local lan interface 10.51.31.2 , I am running openvpn client on this
3) the traffic from this local interface VPNServer:vpnPort ( x.x.x.x:1194) not getting NAT to my public facing interface (sierra)